# Read image from file, then delete file

Tags: image, c++-cli, delete-file

i open photo in my app, using the following Code:

```
Image^ image = Image::FromFile("Image.jpg");

pictureBox1->ImageLocation="Image.jpg";

FileInfo^ FileInfoStr = gcnew FileInfo("Image.jpg");
```

now, for delete photo of system, using the following Code:

```
File::Delete("Image.jpg");
```

or

```
FileInfo^ FileInfoStr = gcnew FileInfo("Image.jpg");
FileInfoStr->Delete();
```

or

```
DeleteFile("Image.jpg");
```

but the codes does not work

Error

can not delete the file, the file is open in another program

help me for delete file.

Comment: Did you close the file before you tried to delete it?

Comment: Give this a read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8th8381z(v=vs.110).aspx . Of special interest: "Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the Image. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the Image object's Finalize method."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image::FromFile` keeps the file locked.  What you can do instead is:

1. Open the file in binary mode (`FileStream`)
2. Read the entire content of the `FileStream` into a `MemoryStream`
3. Close the file
4. Create the `Image` object using the `MemoryStream`

Another approach is to `Clone` the `Image`, then dispose of the original `Image` object and use the cloned instance.  The clone manages its own memory, without retaining a reference to the original stream.